# How to call specific URL in jquery repeatedly after some time interval?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery . My purpose is to just send a request to web server to keep session alive. I am using code below to call a particular url from jsp page.

```
$.get('http://localhost/test.html',function(data,status) {
    },'html');
```

I used setinterval in the following way to call this url in each 5 seconds :

```
<script>

setInterval(
function ()
{
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.   
    $.get('http://localhost/test.html',function(data,status) {
    },'html');  
}, 5000);

</script>
```

I am not able to figure out that why call is not going when I load the page . Note : this call should occur in every 5 seconds .

Please help .I searched internet a lot. But was not able to find the solution .

Comment: What you've done should work (provided you have a script tag somewhere loading jQuery, and that's above your code shown). It's a bit odd that the data you're sending the server is `'html'`, but it should work.

Comment: Why don't you try extracting the code in the setInterval() out, and call like the following? That's more clear when reading.

setInterval(function(){methodName();}, 10000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what you're doing is a `GET`, the browser is allowed to cache it, because HTTP `GET` calls are meant to be idempotent (they don't change anything). You can prevent that by:

1. Using cache control headers on the server, or
2. Using `POST` instead of `GET`, or
3. Using the longer form of `ajax` that lets you specify options, and specifying the `cache: false` option.

   FWIW, the equivalent `ajax` call for your `get`, plus the `cache` option, is:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url:     'http://localhost/test.html',
     cache:   false,
     data:    'html',
     success: function(data,status) {
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Or add a time-stamp to the call in order to send a "fresh" request and avoid caching.

Comment: And is talking about when the page is getting loaded so it's not seems as a cache issue, even not one request has submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code, if it's really not working, it's seems like an ambient issue (Caching, Missing references etc.). I tries your code and insert an `alert()` call into the callback and it seems to work perfectly.

You've probably forgot to reference jQuery or didn't analyze the network traffic. Put this reference in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

And the working code is:

```
setInterval(
function ()
{
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.   
    $.get('http://localhost/test.html',function(data,status) {
        alert('GET Request Happen!');
    },'html');  
}, 5000);
```

Look at my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RjKjQ/